# How to get Gutenberg Gallery Block to output thumbnail images?

Tags: block-editor, gallery, thumbnails

By default, the Gutenberg Gallery Block outputs full size images in 3 columns. This is excessive, especially on mobile, so I would like to set it in the theme or function file to output thumbnails. How do I do this? Changing the image size option in the Gallery settings seems to have no effect.

[image: image size option in the Gallery settings]

*(I suspect this is because my homemade theme doesn't support these options correctly, but I cannot find any documentation on theming for new Gutenberg blocks).*

Answer (score 0):

I know it's hard to believe but it's known and still unresolved issue in WordPress. It's impossible to output thumbnail size in Gutenberg Gallery Block.